# Cannot include JS files in ExpressJS served index file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm building a web application at the moment, which has multiple pages incorporated. Each of these pages, however, have multiple views. The original design was to set each of the pages up as an SPA and just serve the `index.html` from the Node.js back-end and let React.js handle all the view routing.

This has proven to be more complex than I thought. Here is the issue.

The Node.js route (snippet):

```
router.get("/", function(request, response){
    response.sendFile("/index.html", {
        root: __dirname + "/../client/pages/home/"
    });
});
```

But then in `index.html` (snippet):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>New Website</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Welcome to my website..</h1>

    <div id="App">
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `index.js` is not being included. When the browser tries to include `index.js` it's requesting the route `www.example.com/index.js` from the Node.js server which is obviously not set up so I'm getting a `Cannot GET /index.js` response.

Each of the SPAs are in their individual folders with `index.html` and `index.js`. Creating a public folder with all the js files is not an option at the moment.

==========================================================================

## SOLVED: THIS IS THE CODE I USED

`clientController.js`

```
module.exports = function(app){
    router.get("/", function(request, response){
        app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/../client/pages/page1/"));
        response.sendFile("index.html", {
            root: __dirname + "/../client/pages/page1/"
        });
    });

    router.get("/page2/*", function(request, response){
        app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/../client/pages/page2/"));
        response.sendFile("index.html", {
            root: __dirname + "/../client/pages/page2/"
        });
    });

    return router;
};
```

`server.js`

```
var routes = require("controllers/clientController.js");
app.use("/", routes);
```

The accepted answer, I had to add in the `sendFile()` line as well to prevent the request from hanging. This settles the response and allows for the correct paths for file includes in the HTML files.

Comment: You need to make sure your `express` has a static directory module enabled. Also, if it's truly SPA you can separate HTML and API into separate projects alltogether.

Comment: The entire project is not SPA. There are multiple pages, which I went setting up each page as an SPA because they each have 3/4 views.

Comment: You don't need to put the app.use(...) in the router.get(...). This will incur a overhead on every time you make a request.

Comment: @bilalba Without the app.use() my problem is not solved?

Comment: What I meant to say is, just write those outside the router.get(...)

Comment: Oh okay, so just make every page static? Rather than use a router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory will be treated as static. You don't need to make a separate directory or define a separate route.

```
router.use(express.static( __dirname + "/../client/pages/home/"));
```

Comment: I would have to write a route for every include from every page then.

Comment: This is not possible @bilalba. I would have to make a route for every include. It would be far too many and counter productive.

Comment: Yes, sorry. The answer was not refreshing.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [ExpressJs documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) , you have to use `express.static(root, [options])` to create a middleware that manage you website. This is the only built-in middleware function in Express.

## Express app example:

Before all you have to init you express app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Then you start adding your middleware:

**Note:** You can add multiple middlewares, and chain them sequentially. In other words, you can add headers handler before your website middleware.

#### Headers middleware handler example:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    /* you can also handle https redirection */
    // if (req.protocol != "https") {
    //     res.writeHead(301, {"Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url});
    //     res.end();
    //     return;
    // }

    // here you can config you response headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');


    next(); // this will pass the request to the next middleware  
});
```

#### Website router example:

To create middleware website with ExpressJs, you have to use `express.static` with your relative website folder, and name you default page `index.html`

```
app.use("/", express.static('PATH_TO_WEBSITE FOLDER'));
```

## Full ExpressJs app example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    /* you can also handle https redirection */
    // if (req.protocol != "https") {
    //     res.writeHead(301, {"Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url});
    //     res.end();
    //     return;
    // }

    // here you can config you response headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');


    next(); // this will pass the request to the next middleware  
});


app.use("/", express.static('PATH_TO_WEBSITE FOLDER'));


var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(80, "HERE_PUT_YOUR_DOMAIN", function () {
    console.log('HTTP: express-example running on port ' + 80 + '.');
});
```