# ExpressJS: how to include a transpiled .js file in HTML as static resource

Tags: typescript, express

I'm trying to set up ExpressJS to serve transpiled TypeScript files out of a directory so I can include them in my `index.html`. I keep getting a 404 on `/components/foo.js` when running this setup.

```js
/* /dist/server.js: */
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('/components', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/components')));

var options = {
    root: __dirname + '/dist/components/',
  };

app.get('/', function(req: any, res: any) {
    res.sendFile('/index.html', options);
});

app.listen(8090);
```

```html
<!-- /public/index.html -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>demo</title> 
        <script src="/components/foo.js" type="module"></script>
    </head>   
    <body>
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my folder structure:

[image]

**Question:** What is the most sensible way to set up the folder structure and the `server.ts` in order to be able to include certain transpiled `.js` in my `index.html`?

**P.S.:** I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331826/cannot-include-js-files-in-expressjs-served-index-file) and tried a variation of their approach but it didn't work: I don't understand what they're doing and so am shooting in the dark.

Comment: Print out your static setting path: `console.log(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/components'))`

Comment: @hoangdv yes! thank you - this was key in getting me to see my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the most sensible way to set up the folder structure and the server.ts in order to be able to include certain transpiled `.js` in my `index.html`?

I would serve the folder containing the transpiled codes as `static`, preferrably with `virtual path`.

You could serve `components` folder assuming it contains the transpiled codes safe to be exposed publicly

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/components')); // server.js and components are in the same folder

// Then in your html you could simply, notice the absolute path
<script src="/static/foo.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks to @hoangdv comment I saw that your solution is technically correct, was just me spinning in circles.